# Django - MigrationError after I add a new field into existing model and mongoDb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I have a MigrationError when a django view executes the get function of a model object `user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)`

the exeption as below :

```
HTTP GET /media/website/bg_chat.PNG 200 [0.22, 127.0.0.1:1417]
Internal Server Error: /chat/French
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 287, in _align_results
    ret.append(doc[selected.column])
KeyError: 'numberOfBan'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\chat\views.py", line 32, in chatroom
    uprofile = UserProfil.objects.get(user=user)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1005, in apply_converters
    for row in map(list, rows):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1466, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1466, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 59, in fetchmany
    ret.append(self.result.next())
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 719, in __next__
    return next(self._result_generator)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 725, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 180, in __iter__
    yield self._align_results(doc)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\MS_ ISI\PA\Mini_Projet\ISI_Chat\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 290, in _align_results
    raise MigrationError(selected.column)
djongo.sql2mongo.MigrationError: numberOfBan
```

And the UserProfile model :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    SEXE = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DateBirth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=UploadTo)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEXE)
    #New fields
    numberOfBan = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lastBan = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

TO KNOW :

- First, I used the default database sqLite and after it I switch to noSQL database mongoDB and all worked fine.
- after I add some field to the userProfile model I run the migrations commands and also worked fine.
- I checked the collection of database and it has the field 'lastBan' as  expected and 'int32' instead of 'numberOfBan' in some document and another does not have the new fields at all!
- And when I add a new userprofile it has the two fields in the document but with the same exception problem.

Any idea please ??

Comment: Did you create a field in your `mongoDB` collection with the relation? Usually you need to create a field then inspect the DB and then you go for migrations, precisely in this order.

Comment: No, I just  create fields in the model and then I run migrations, should I create it in mongoDb first ??

Comment: That way, **mongoDB** doesn't have the field and you're running migrations so the error is obvious.

Comment: Ooh yes that's it, I'm new in noSql, thanks for your help ans2human